# Is there an open source netflow collector C++ library set?

Tags: c++, netflow

I am looking for a C++ library set to develop my own C++ daemon in Linux for collecting NetFlow information. Does anyone know of an open source one or a library set that is available?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried Googling? There are plenty of daemons for NetFlow available, for Linux and BSD flavors:

- http://www.mindrot.org/projects/softflowd/
- http://fprobe.sourceforge.net/
- http://lionet.info/ipcad/

Comment: I have but I require DB support and we already have our own DB so it needs to fit this. Therefore I thought it may be the best plan to look at a library set as we have done for net-snmp.

Answer (score 2):

For a stand-alone library, you can try "libipfix".  It implements the newer IETF IPFIX protocol, but also understands Netflow v9 (on which IPFIX is based).  But I don't think it can process older Netflow versions (v1 and v5 are common), so this is probably only useful if your Netflow-exporting devices support Netflow v9.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW - take a look also at http://code.google.com/p/flowd/ - it's small and BSD-licensed, so you should be able to tweak it according to your needs. (I'm not affiliated with it at all, just used a few times, and liked the tiny footprint).

Answer (score 1):

"[Vermont](https://github.com/tumi8/vermont)" is an open source modular Ipfix/Netflow probe/aggregator/collector application written in C++. It can be configured in a wide variety of ways to collect and process flow related information. It has reasonable [documentation with examples](https://github.com/tumi8/vermont/wiki) detailing how to combine it's modules.

[image: Vermont]